# Android Application that displays new messages posted on a server

Tags: android, sockets, connection, power-management

I am looking for reading resources or sample applications that can help me hammer out the following application workflow:

1. The client application establishes a connection to our server
2. The client application scans for updates on a regular interval
3. If an administrator has posted a new message, the new message is displayed in a widget.

I currently have 2 concerns:

1. I want to ensure that the monitoring service is not a major battery drain.
2. What is the most secure and simple method to establish the connection to retrieve data?
   ....There are a lot of suggestions out there... I need to know what method I should be researching over all others. Currently, all options are on the table because I have yet configure our server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of questions here, I'll try to give a succinct answer.

For the infrastructure I would go with HTTP REST calls to retrieve JSON data reprsenting your messages. **[Here](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-simple-httpclient-to.html)** is a decent link about writing an HTTP REST client for android, there are many others online.

For security, I would definitely start with **SSL**, but if you need to authenticate the requests I would also look at **[OAuth](http://oauth.net/)** to secure you remote API.

Comment: I am more familiar with XML, personally. Is there a significant benefit to using JSON over XML?

Comment: The biggest benefit is that if you ever had a companion website for your app, that javascript and related libraries in the web world can consume JSON more easily.  But strictly speaking in compiled java code either one would work fine.  There are many libraries to serialize JSON and XML to/from java objects.

Answer (score 1):

As far as A, Have you considered using [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) (aka "push") to trigger the updates? Then there's no client bandwidth beyond what is being used anyways for the Market/GMail/Talk connection. If you need to support Android versions below 2.2 it's not really an option at the moment, though.

Otherwise there's a few good examples of being a good citizen when polling from a widget; Jeff Sharkey's [android-sky](http://code.google.com/p/android-sky/) is probably the oldest, best, and most authoritative.

For B, unless I'm misunderstanding your need it's pretty hard to beat HTTPS; rolling your own "secure" transport over vanilla HTTP or anything lower-level is just asking for a disaster.